# Should i animate the Color Setting of a lamp or its Strength?

Tags: light, keyframes

Im experimenting with eevee a bit and i was wondering if there was any difference between increasing the brightness of a lamp by using its Color Settings or by using its Strength/Power/Energy Setting.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the color setting will change the emitted color while changing the strength will only change how powerfull the emission is. The difference might not be visible in the render, but AFAIK it will make a difference if you do compositing on your render or export exr/hdr pictures for editing on other softwares.